# action script getUrl issue

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

am facing an problem using getUrl in as2 , when i run the swf using test movie the link work probably , but if i run the published file am getting a wrong url , example

-run via test movie : getting -> www.google.com 
 -run the published swf file : getting ->file:///C:/Users/moata/Desktop/actionScript/www.google.com

```
dots.ignoreWhite = true;
dots.load('links.xml');

dots.onLoad = function(success:Boolean){
    if(success){
        xmlNode = this.firstChild;
        var all:MovieClip = attachMovie("test","all",depth);
        setTimeout(startMe,6000);
    }else{
        trace("Could not load XML");
    }

    function startMe (){

        for(i=1;i<=6;i++){

            all['btn'+i].onRelease = function() {

                for(i=0;i<6;i++){
                    var name = this;
                    if(String(xmlNode.childNodes[i].attributes.TITLE) == String(name)){
                        getURL(xmlNode.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue, "_blank");
                    }
                }       
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i just need add http:// in getRUL as follow 
getURL("http://www.google.com"); , instead of  getURL("www.google.com");